# Code::Blocks fortran source formatting issues

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

I just started using the Code::Blocks editor for Fortran because a friend suggested it. I can't get the source formatter to work properly. For this simple code segment:

```
print *,'hello moon'
!left = (mybankact-tax) * number1
!iowe = stuff-1;
```

I get this, when I use "Format using AStyle"

```
print *,'hello moon'
!left = (mybankact-tax) * number1
        !iowe = stuff-1;
```

I get these strange indents all the way down my code. Anyone know how to get this to work? This is driving me nuts. (Or other good editors for Fortran - I don't need to compile code, just edit and jump between functions, which code::blocks is great for.)

By the way, the file extension is ".90" and all the syntax highlighting works fine, so code::blocks seems to recognize this is Fortran okay.

Comment: This issue is more serious when I have "if" and "end if" - my code is undesirably indented all the way down like a never-ending staircase.

Comment: Is the suffix `.90` or `.f90`? Just to confirm,  I can't help either way.

Comment: It's `.f90` - sorry for the typo. Does the source formatter work for you though? I have multiple files formatted in really odd ways and it's making them very hard to read, so this formatter could really be handy if it worked.

Comment: Look for patch #183 for Codeblocks Astyle.  You will need to rebuild /usr/lib/codeblocks/plugins/libastyle.so with this patch installed.  This is something I don't know how to do, which is why this is not an answer.

Comment: @cup Thanks - I'll try to see if I can figure it out and let you know.